# How do I call a angularJS function after a row selection event in django

Tags: angularjs, django

I need to display the selected row id when a row selection event occurs in datatable worklist. I'm trying to do with an angularJS function as below,

```
function selectedrows($scope){

        dtWorklist = datatable_worklist.get_selected_rows;
        if (dtWorklist.length>0) {
        console.log("dt", dtWorklist[0].id);}
    }

    selectedrows($scope);
```

How do I call the function which I created after the row selection event? Will it be a proper way to create an event and call the function? Or could it be done by giving a load time to this function? Any new approaches is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click or ng-dbclick event to call your function

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in datatable_worklist ng-click="selectedrows(data)"  ng-dblclick="selectedrows(data)" >
```

in your controller define selectedrows function

```
$scope.selectedrows = function (data){
console.log(data.id);
}
```